# Open a PDF with a word highlighted according to a link clicked on an HTML page

Tags: pdf, keyword, highlighting

Is it possible to open a PDF on clicking a link in a web page, at a certain page with a certain word highlighted. E.g. my app scans keywords in pdf docs and prints a summary of their appearances. It would be nice if the user could click a link and have the PDF open at the correct page with all instances of that word being highlighted on the open page.

Is this possible - or something similar if not this exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely -- append URL parameters as described in this document:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Did this work for you? I thought that using Search would just return the first page found as opposed to a specific page? My tests have shown that this is the case. It's seemingly impossible to select text in a document on a specific page using PDF open parameters